# CSS sliding is overlapping to sticky top menu bar

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, frontend, react-bootstrap

The logic is to stick the menubar 2nd div when scrolling and other divs should go under the sticky menubar. But here only 3rd div sliding banner is overlapping to sticky and others are working fine.

Can anyone help with this issue, please?

All divs are inside the react Router.

CSS

```
  .sticky {
      width: 100%;
      height: 75px;
      color: #61dafb;
    background-color: blue;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      }
    .slider-main {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        background-image: url(../images/slide_1.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;

        animation: slide 10s infinite;
      }
      @keyframes slide {
        0%{
          background-image: url(../images/slide_1.jpg);
          width: auto;
          height: 500px;
        }
        26%{
          width: auto;
          height: 500px;
          background-image: url(../images/slide_2.jpg);

        }
       67%{
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
          background-image: url(../images/slide_3.jpg);
        }

      }
    /* slider text 1*/
    .tx-anim-1{
      width: 457px;
      height: 76px;
      margin: auto;
      background-image: url(../images/slider-tx-bg.png);

      text-align: center;
      color:yellow;
      font-size: 50px;
      position: relative;
      animation: mymove1 4s ;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
    }

    @keyframes mymove1 {
      from {top: -10%;}
      to {top: 64%;}
    }
    /* slider text 2*/
    .tx-anim-2{
      width: 457px;
      height: 35px;
      margin-top: 320px;
      text-align: center;
      background-image: url(../images/slider-tx-bg.png);
      color: #54ff00;
      font-size: 22px;
      position: relative;
      animation: mymove2 4s ;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;

    }

    @keyframes mymove2 {
      from {left: -30%;}
      to {left: 35%;}
    }
    /* slider text 3*/
    .tx-anim-3{
      width: 550px;
      height: 35px;
     margin-top: 150px;
      margin-left: 32%;

      background-image: url(../images/slider-tx-bg.png);
      text-align: center;
      color:yellow;
      font-size: 18px;
      position: relative;
      animation: mymove3 4s ;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
    }

    @keyframes mymove3 {
      from {bottom: 0%;}
      to {bottom: 30%;}
    }
```

1st div

```
            <div>
                <div>
                    PU AMD AM4 Socket for AMD Ryzen/ AMD Ryzen 2nd Generation/Ryzen with Radeon Vega Graphics/Ryzen 1st
                    Generation/7th Generation A-series/Athlon X4/Athlon Processors Supports CPU up to 8 cores. The maximum memory frequency
                </div>
            </div>
```

2nd div

```
         <div className="mycontainer sticky">
                <Navbar className=" site-bg  " expand="lg">
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                        <div>
                            <img src={logo} alt="logo" width="200" />
                            {/*   <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "./images/logo.png"} alt="mypic" width="200" /> */}
                        </div>
                    </Navbar.Brand>

                    <Navbar.Toggle className="border-0" aria-controls="navbar-toggle" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="navbar-toggle" bsStyle="tabs" style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
                        <Nav className="ml-auto">
                            <Link className="my-navbar" to="/">Home</Link>
                            <Link className="my-navbar" to="/about">About</Link>
                            <Link className="my-navbar" to="/services">Services</Link>
                            <Link className="my-navbar" to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                            <Link className="my-navbar" to="/galleries">Galleries</Link>

                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
```

3rd div

```
<div className="slider-main">
            <div className="tx-anim-1">
                <div>
                    Decor and Event
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="tx-anim-2">
                <div style={{ paddingTop: 5 }}>
                    A management Company
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="tx-anim-3">
                <div style={{ paddingTop: 5 }}>
                    We promise you the best Deal with full Satisfaction.
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

4th div

```
            <div style={{ paddingTop: 50 }}>
                <Route defaultActiveKey="/home" path="/" exact render={() => <HomePage title={this.state.home.title} subTitle={this.state.home.subTitle} text={this.state.home.text} />} className="container-full" />
                <Route path="/about" render={() => <AboutPage title={this.state.about.title} subTitle={this.state.about.subTitle} text={this.state.about.text} />} />
                <Route path="/services" render={() => <ServicesPage title={this.state.services.title} />} />
                <Route path="/contact" render={() => <ContactPage title={this.state.contact.title} />} />
                <Route path="/galleries" render={() => <GalleriesPage title={this.state.galleries.title} />} />
                <Footer />
            </div>
```

Comment: can you create snippet of it or host it on heroku so we will solve your problem

Comment: ok let me know and try snippet and Heroku and how to use it, because I am new in this

Comment: you can search on youtube, how can I upload my project on heroku

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUW5GAFhu6s&t=21s...........---from this...
this is the error came........when I tried........."Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail"   whatup no. 8553741736

Comment: See Heroku logs, something are failed to execute, like your .env files data

Comment: https://github.com/thokchomrs/sticky-banner     I tried this to connect heroku but no luck. can you check with this link to access the codes

Comment: nice, it took a long time because you do not come with the live snippet. so please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a problem of `z-index`, you can easily manage it with CSS. Just add below CSS properties on your classes and your problem will be solved and remember I added `background-color` because it shows, except slider all go under from the sticky menu.

```
.mycontainer{
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: skyblue;
}

.slider-main {
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Comment: Thank you: yes, it is working. Now only the slider is giving the issue. If you have any solution let me know. Because still stuck in this slider

Comment: Hi Shah. it is working now-slider also, hope due to browser catch. Thanks Bro

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: can you please check and help this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491994/react-bootstrap-navdropdown-is-hiding-under-the-things-below-menubar-overlaping#     If I remove sticky to normal headerbar then it is working the dropdown.